# Trouble with Python script from rc.local (TTY issue?)

Tags: python, boot

I have not been able to find a solution to an issue affecting one of my Python programs only when it runs from `rc.local`.

Update added to the end with additional information.

A brief description of what I am trying to do:

A Raspberry Pi 3, when started, starts a slideshow using feh, and also drives a counter made of 7-segment digits. A small interface panel with some pushbuttons will be provided to adjust the counter. One button is intended to kill the slideshow, then open a PyGame window to adjust the counter, which is right now split to 2 buttons for troubleshooting. Exiting from the PyGame window updates the counter and starts the slideshow back up. `/etc/rc.local` calls a python program called `main.py`.

`/etc/rc.local` (commented lines removed for brevity):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
sleep 30
sudo python /home/pi/Scripts/main.py &
exit 0
```

This program monitors the buttons for the interface.

`~/Scripts/main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

time.sleep(30)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def Shutdown(channel):
         os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")

def StopSlideshow(channel):
         os.system("sudo pkill feh")

def StartAdjust(channel):
         os.system('sudo python /home/pi/Scripts/StartAdjust.py &')

os.system("sudo bash /home/pi/Scripts/slideshow.sh &")
os.system("sudo python /home/pi/Scripts/ShiftTest.py &")

GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING, callback = Shutdown, bouncetime = 2000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback = StopSlideshow, bouncetime = 2000)
GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.FALLING, callback = StartAdjust, bouncetime = 2000)

while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
```

The problem I have is that `StartAdjust.py` does not start on GPIO24. If I change StartAdjust for another simple program, it works fine. Also, if I kill the process `main.py` started by `rc.local`, then start it from command line, it works as intended.

`~/Scripts/StartAdjust.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime

up = 25
left = 12
right = 16
down = 26
enter = 13

buttons = {up,left,right,down,enter}

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
for x in buttons:
        GPIO.setup(x, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
def UpdateDT():
        text_surface = font_big.render('%i'%year, True, BLACK)
        rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(120,150))
        window.blit(text_surface, rect)
        text_surface = font_big.render('%i'%month, True, BLACK)
        rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(240,150))
        window.blit(text_surface, rect)
        text_surface = font_big.render('%i'%date, True, BLACK)
        rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(360,150))
        window.blit(text_surface, rect)
        text_surface = font_big.render('%i'%hour, True, BLACK)
        rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(480,150))
        window.blit(text_surface, rect)

def UpdateEdit(EditPosition):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, PosYear, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, PosMonth, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, PosDate, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, PosHour, 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, PosExit, 2)
        if EditPosition == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, RED, PosYear, 2)
        if EditPosition == 2:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, RED, PosMonth, 2)
        if EditPosition == 3:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, RED, PosDate, 2)
        if EditPosition == 4:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, RED, PosHour, 2)
        if EditPosition == 5:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, RED, PosExit, 2)

#set tuples for later use
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
PosYear = (60, 130, 120, 40)
EditYear = (62, 132, 116, 36)
PosMonth = (180, 130, 120, 40)
EditMonth = (182, 132, 116, 36)
PosDate = (300, 130, 120, 40)
EditDate = (302, 132, 116, 36)
PosHour = (420, 130, 120, 40)
EditHour = (422, 132, 116, 36)
PosExit = (540, 130, 120, 40)

#get last reset time from file and set variables
file = open('/home/pi/Scripts/Date.txt', 'r')
ResetTime = int(file.read())
file.close()
year = int(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ResetTime).strftime('%Y'))
month = int(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ResetTime).strftime('%m'))
date = int(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ResetTime).strftime('%d'))
hour = int(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ResetTime).strftime('%H'))

#set up PyGame window
os.putenv('SDL_FBDEV', '/dev/fb1')
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "100,100"
pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((750,250))
window.fill(WHITE)
font_big = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
#set up static text
text_surface = font_big.render('Enter start time', True, BLACK)
rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(300,50))
window.blit(text_surface, rect)
text_surface = font_big.render('Year', True, BLACK)
rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(120,100))
window.blit(text_surface, rect)
text_surface = font_big.render('Month', True, BLACK)
rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(240,100))
window.blit(text_surface, rect)
text_surface = font_big.render('Date', True, BLACK)
rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(360,100))
window.blit(text_surface, rect)
text_surface = font_big.render('Hour', True, BLACK)
rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(480,100))
window.blit(text_surface, rect)
text_surface = font_big.render('Exit', True, BLACK)
rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(600,150))
window.blit(text_surface, rect)

#draw editing marker
EditPos = 1
pygame.draw.rect(window, RED, PosYear, 2)
UpdateDT()
pygame.display.update()

#main editing routine

while 1:
        os.system('sudo python /home/pi/Scripts/Dummy.py &')
        if GPIO.input(right) == False:
                if EditPos < 5:
                        EditPos += 1
                        UpdateEdit(EditPos)
                        pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.25)
        if GPIO.input(left) == False:
                if EditPos > 1:
                         EditPos -= 1
                         UpdateEdit(EditPos)
                         pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.25)
        if GPIO.input(up) == False:
                if EditPos == 1:
                        if year < 2037:
                                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, EditYear, 0)
                                year += 1
                                UpdateDT()
                                pygame.display.update()
                elif EditPos == 2:
                        if month < 12:
                                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, EditMonth, 0)
                                month += 1
                                UpdateDT()
                                pygame.display.update()
                 elif EditPos == 3:
                        if date < 31:
                                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, EditDate, 0)
                                date += 1
                                UpdateDT()
                                pygame.display.update()
                elif EditPos == 4:
                        if hour < 23:
                                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, EditHour, 0)
                                hour += 1
                                UpdateDT()
                                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.25)
        if GPIO.input(down) == False:
                if EditPos == 1:
                        if year > 1970:
                                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, EditYear, 0)
                                year -= 1
                                UpdateDT()
                                pygame.display.update()
                elif EditPos == 2:
                        if month > 1:
                                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, EditMonth, 0)
                                month -= 1
                                UpdateDT()
                                pygame.display.update()
                elif EditPos == 3:
                        if date > 1:
                                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, EditDate, 0)
                                date -= 1
                                UpdateDT()
                                pygame.display.update()
                elif EditPos == 4:
                       if hour > 0:
                                pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, EditHour, 0)
                                hour -= 1
                                UpdateDT()
                                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(0.25)
        if GPIO.input(enter) == False:
                if EditPos == 5:
                        TimeTuple = datetime.datetime(year, month, date, hour, 0, 0, 0)
                        ResetTime = time.mktime(TimeTuple.timetuple())
                        file = open('/home/pi/Scripts/Date.txt', 'w')
                        file.write(str(int(ResetTime)))
                        file.close()
                        os.system("sudo python /home/pi/Scripts/ShiftTest.py &")
                        os.system("sudo bash /home/pi/Scripts/slideshow.sh &")
                        exit()
```

A few other notes:

- `Date.txt` is a file that holds the Unix time.
- `ShiftTest.py` reads `Date.txt` and compares it to actual time the calculate the number to display (currently minutes difference). It is also run by a cron job to periodically update.
- `slideshow.sh` starts the slideshow.

EDIT

The PyGame window does not open. I ran `ps -ef` and `StartAdjust.py` does not show to be running. I originally had:

```
def StopSlideshow(channel):
     os.system("sudo pkill feh")
     os.system('sudo python /home/pi/Scripts/StartAdjust.py &')
```

and the first command would run but the second would not.

UPDATE:
I had a little time to spend on it today, and checked a few more things:

- On startup, the process `/bin/sh -e /etc/rc.local start` is running as `root` with a TTY of `?`
- When this starts `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Scripts/main.py`, it is also running as `root` with a TTY of `?`. This is when I have the noted issue.
- If I kill the process `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Scripts/main.py`, and run `/bin/sh/ -e /etc/rc.local start &`, the process `bash /etc/rc.local` runs as `pi` with a TTY of `pts/0`.
- `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Scripts/main.py` is then started by `rc.local`, with a user of `pi` and a TTY of `pts/0`, and this works as intended.
- If I run `sudo /bin/sh/ -e /etc/rc.local start &`, it runs as `root` and TTY of `pts/0`, as does `main.py`, and the program works as intended.

The only difference I see is TTY, but I do not know yet how to proceed. Is it possibly a combination of the wrong console, and using PyGame? I am pretty new to this in general, and have never had to manipulate consoles, if that is the right term.

Thank you